# vb.net My.Settings

Tags: vb.net, my.settings

Is there a way to create `my.settings` variables dynamically?
I want to generate my.settings variables depending on values in my data base so the number my.settings variables need to vary from time to time.

If i had the following values in my database,

```
0
2
6
13
77
```

the names of my.settings variables generated will be

```
My.Settings.M0
My.Settings.M2
My.Settings.M6
My.Settings.M13
My.Settings.M77
```

So I want to create those variables on the applications first run.
Question after getting the numbers from the Database. How to i create those variables with code?

Also is there a way to remove them with code Because when the values of the database changes and the value does not exist, I then need to remove its variable?

Also i would like some suggestions, If this isn't in a good way.

Comment: Since you wouldn't be able to reference runtime-generated properties when actually writing your code, what is the reason you want to do this?  I don't see anything to be gained.  It seems like you could probably redesign your process to just use a list or dictionary, intead.

Comment: each number has a percentage assosiated with it, and i use this percentage to do some calculation in the row that a specific number exists for example value 2 may exist in 33000 records, and some times this percentage changes so the user should be able to edit it from a textbox, so the my.settings variables will be used to store percetages which are editable from text boxes

Comment: also text boxes are generated dynamicly depending on how many different numbers i have

Comment: I would say that you would be better off placing such logic into a `Dictionary(Of Int, Decimal)`. If you are using `My.Settings` just for a common shared object, then create your dictionary in a static helper class.

Comment: and it will save the changes that a user made to the percentages when he runs the application again?

Comment: If you implement that functionality, yes. Are you looking to save those values for everyone (back to the database) or just for the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Project Settings don't seem to do well with serializing and saving values beyond the basic types. What you can do is use a User-scoped string-valued setting to store a serialized Dictionary.

For my example, I created a setting named `SerializedKeyPercentDictionary` of Type `string` and Scope `User`. I am using JSON for my serialization, as it creates a string of smaller length than most other serializations. For this, you will need to add a reference to System.Runtime.Serializations. With this setting and that reference in place, you can then make a global helper class to provide a strongly-typed dictionary for managing your key-to-percent mapping:

```
Public Class KeyPercentHelper
    Private Shared _keyPercentDictionary As Dictionary(Of Integer, Decimal)
    Private Shared _initLock As Object = New Object()

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property KeyPercentDictionary As Dictionary(Of Integer, Decimal)
        Get
            If (_keyPercentDictionary Is Nothing) Then
                InitializeDictionary()
            End If
            Return _keyPercentDictionary
        End Get
    End Property

    Shared Sub New()
        AddHandler My.Settings.SettingsLoaded, AddressOf HandleSettingsLoad
        AddHandler My.Settings.SettingsSaving, AddressOf HandleSettingsSaving
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub InitializeDictionary()
        ' Load dictionary from User Setting.
        SyncLock _initLock
            If (_keyPercentDictionary Is Nothing) Then
                If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(My.Settings.SerializedKeyPercentDictionary)) Then
                    _keyPercentDictionary = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Decimal)()
                Else
                    Dim ser As New System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(Dictionary(Of Integer, Decimal)))
                    Using memStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
                        Using writer As New System.IO.StreamWriter(memStream)
                            writer.Write(My.Settings.SerializedKeyPercentDictionary)
                            writer.Flush()
                            memStream.Position = 0
                            _keyPercentDictionary = CType(ser.ReadObject(memStream), Dictionary(Of Integer, Decimal))
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End If
            End If
        End SyncLock
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub HandleSettingsLoad(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        If (_keyPercentDictionary Is Nothing) Then
            InitializeDictionary()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Shared Sub HandleSettingsSaving(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Ensure User Setting value is updated before save.
        Dim ser As New System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(Dictionary(Of Integer, Decimal)))
        Using memStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
            ser.WriteObject(memStream, _keyPercentDictionary)
            memStream.Position = 0
            Using reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(memStream)
                My.Settings.SerializedKeyPercentDictionary = reader.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This is great and works perfectly. FYI, you need to add a reference to System.ServiceModel.Web to get access to System.Runtime.Serialization.Json. Thanks!